# Masking sensitive Data in SQL Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, data-masking

Dears,

please I have a column with a SerialID like Below which I need to mask it using a SQL query

```
|SerialID            |
|--------------------|
|00027083691581342079|
|00027139741580324755|
|00027016011583677218|
|00027016011583677218|
|00027139061577873262|
|00027056351580383150|
|00027143131580371648|
|00027143131580371648|
|00027143131580371648|
|00027147651583526704|
```

to be the output like the below

```
|SerialID            |NewID|
|--------------------|-----|
|00027083691581342079|1    |
|00027139741580324755|2    |
|00027016011583677218|3    |
|00027016011583677218|3    |
|00027139061577873262|4    |
|00027056351580383150|5    |
|00027143131580371648|6    |
|00027143131580371648|6    |
|00027143131580371648|6    |
|00027147651583526704|7    |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank()`:

```
select serialid, dense_rank() over (order by serialid) as newid
from t;
```

EDIT:

I have had experience on some parallel systems that the following is faster:

```
select t.*, newid       
from t join
     (select serialid, 
             row_number() over (order by serialid) as newid
      from t
      group by serialid
     ) tt
     on t.serialid = tt.serialid;
```

Some databases need to sort all the data on a single node because there is no `partition by` using the `dense_rank()`.  The aggregation query reduces the amount of data so it can significantly improve performance -- but I'm not sure if this trick works in Teradata.

Comment: order isn't quite right to get exact expected results; but assumes it's not important. as it's not really defined in question; and insufficient information exists to make a determination.

Comment: It works very fine but it takes much time as I have about 6 million distinct SerialID, the Rank doesn't matter for me,

Comment: Are you extracting many other columns in the real query, besides SerialID and NewID? Or are there very large numbers of rows for some SerialID? If so it may be better to build a SerialID/NewID xref in a subquery and join back to the original table.

Comment: @AhmedMohammedAbdelKader . . . How many rows are in the table and how many serial ids?  This should be faster than alternative methods.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have about 80 million rows and the number is increasing, and also I have another column beside the SerialID, about 10 other columns

Comment: @GordonLinoff, thanks a lot for your great support, ut works like a charm with Teradata